# Calculus - Optimization - Find max area of a norman window

Tags: calculus, optimization

A Norman window has the shape of a rectangle surmounted by a semicircle. Suppose the outer perimeter of such a window must be 1800 cm. I have to find the base length $x$ which will maximize the area of the window.

There is a picture below, This is an applet, I can change the size by moving the slider.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBwoE.png)

> Question 1) When the base length if 0, the area is 0, There is a limit on how large $x$ can be, when $x$ is large enough, the rectangular portion of the window shrinks to zero height, what is that value of $x$?
>
> Question 2), Determine a function $A(x)$ which gives the area of the window in terms of x.
>
> 3) Now find the exact base length of $x$ which maximizes the area.

Comment: You need to write a formula for the perimeter.  Generally you start with two variables: say, the height and width of the rectangular part (the width will then be used in the semicircle part as well).  Then, use the given perimeter to define one of your variables in terms of the other one.  Then you are able to write the formula for the area of the window using only one variable.  From there you can find the extrema using regular one-variable calculus means.

Comment: @turkeyhundt The perimeter = 1800 so kind of like x*y=1800?

Comment: The perimeter of a semicircle on top of a rectangle $l\times w$ is $l+l+w+w\pi$.  Set that equal to 1800 and you can get the l by itself on one side and be able to define it in terms of w.  Then you can write a formula for the area using only w.